# Como somar o tamanho de todos os arquivos com JS

Tags: javascript, file-upload

Eu tenho um `input file` que recebe vários arquivos, porem eu só consegui pegar o tamanho do primeiro. Gostaria de saber como pegar o tamanho de todos e somar em uma variável;

```
var sizeTotal = $("#inputfileSendTorrent")[0].files[0].size;

<input type="file" multiple name="inputfileSendTorrent[]" id="inputfileSendTorrent">
```

Comment: Você tem um input do tipo file que pode receber vários arquivos e quer saber o tamanho de cada arquivo?

Comment: @Laerte Não, de todos somados.

Comment: Sim, mas o input é do tipo file né? É que você escreveu input size.

Comment: @Laerte Opa, acabei me enganando, já coloquei na pergunta.

Comment: E esse valor deve ser salvo na hora que o cara seleciona ou na hora que ele envia?

Comment: Naquele mesmo lugar ali, no caso esta no `beforeSend:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var getSize = function() {
  var size = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < $("#inputfileSendTorrent")[0].files.length; i++) {
    size += $("#inputfileSendTorrent")[0].files[i].size;
  }

  console.log(size); // apenas para você ver o valor
  return size;
}

// basta chamar a função quando for usar: getSize()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" multiple name="inputfileSendTorrent[]" id="inputfileSendTorrent" onchange="getSize()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Na sua linha

```
var sizeTotal = $("#inputfileSendTorrent")[0].files[0].size;
```

O files é uma array de arquivos e o files[0] é o primeiro da lista.

Você precisa passar em todos os elementos desse array:

```
var sum = 0;
var files = $("#inputfileSendTorrent")[0].files;

for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
  sum += files[i].size;
}
//o resultado está em 'sum': console.log(sum);
```